# MATLAB: How do you calculate the integral of an exponential function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is the code I have used:

```
delta=2*10^-6;
f=@(z) ('exp((z^2)/(2*(delta^2))))/(delta*sqrt(2*pi))');
z=0:(0.1*10^-6):(5*10^-6);
integral(f,0,(5*10^-6))
```

The following error messages come up:

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found
'char'.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 89)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in interfacetemp (line 4)
integral(f,0,(5*10^-6))
```

I'm trying to calculate the following integral: exp((z^2)/(2*(delta^2))))/(delta*sqrt(2*pi)) where delta is the standard deviation of the function and is known to be (2*10^-6). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You will find that you get even better results in calculating the density of the normal distribution if you add a minus sign inside the exponential function. `exp(-z.^2/(2*d^2))/(d*sqrt(2*pi))`

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this code.

```
delta = 2e-6;
f = @(z) exp((z.^2)/(2*(delta.^2)))/(delta*sqrt(2*pi));
integral(f, 0, 5e-6)
```

Your function should not be between quotes and you have to use `.^` to calculate exponent